# How can I dynamically generate a jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a page with multiple divs generated dynamically via PHP/MySQL.  The div class names are also generated dynamically.

```
<div class="1er45">Test 1</div>

<div class="25dd58">Test 2</div>

<div class="87f77">Test 3</div>

<div class="87fffas">Test 4</div>

<div class="1er45">Test 1</div> 

<div class="25dd58">Test 2</div> 

<div class="87fffas">Test 4</div> 

<div class="8asdf">Test 5</div>

<div class="25dd58">Test 2</div> 

<div class="87fffas">Test 4</div> 

<div>...</div>
```

How can I modify this jQuery selector to match all of the dynamically generated div class names above?  I only want to show the first div if there are multiple divs with the same class name.

```
<script>
  $('.classname').not(':first').hide();
</script>
```

Comment: You will need to get a reference to all the divs in question to begin with... Is there a way to add a static class to each div? Or is there a parent element to find all the divs within?

Comment: Considering a jquery selector is nothing more than a string, yes, you certainly can dynamically create a jquery selector. however, you have to know the parts to generate it with beforehand. Though, this is likely an x/y problem, generating a dynamic jquery selector is likely the wrong way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand probably you need to iterate over all `div`'s and hide all same class names occurrences grater than 1 :

```
$( 'div[class]' ).each( function() {
  $( 'div.' + $( this ).attr( 'class' ).replace( /\s/g, '.' ) + ':gt(0)' ).hide();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qvhwL9k/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the point of having a class being dynamically generated.

If you know the pattern of these "ids", you can catch them with a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are only ever going to have one class value in each of those `<div>`'s, you could acheive what you are asking for in the following code:

```
var $firstDiv = $("div:first");
var sFirstClass = $firstDiv.attr("class");

if ($("." + sFirstClass).length < 2) {
    $firstDiv.hide();
}
```

That code would:

1. Retrieve the first `div`
2. Get it's `class` attribute value
3. Checks to see if there is more than one element with that `class` value
4. Hides the first element, if there is not

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through each div, counting occurrences of each class name. Then for each collected class name, hide repeats.

```
var classNames = {};
$('div').each(function(){ 
    var c = $(this).attr('class'); 
    classNames[c] ? classNames[c]++ : classNames[c] = 1;
});

for (var c in classNames) { 
    if (classNames[c] > 1) 
        $('div.' + c).not(':first').hide();   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ne770a5g/